# IE 8 issue for displaying jqchart

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jqchart

I have various sliders in my project. This slider are for the price of different products ,  on the slide of slider I am taking the value of slider dynamically and displaying the pie chart using jq chart [this](http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/chart/charttypes/piechart) . but if I slide 1 slider I cannot see the proper color of pie chart in IE 8 but on slide f 2 sliders it can be seen this issue exists only in IE 8 on IE9 and other browsers it works perfectly fine . What must be the problem ?

below is my java script code

```
$('#pie_chart').jqChart({
    legend: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        border: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            strokeStyle: 'black'
        }
    },

    shadows: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'pie',

        data: data12,

        labels: {
            stringFormat: '%d%',
            valueType: 'percentage',
            font: '12px sans-serif',
            fillStyle: 'white'
        },

        strokeStyle: '#afcd47',
        lineWidth: 1
    }]
});
```

data12 is the array consisting of legend to be displayed and the values for pie chart to show .

Comment: I cannot add image also to show since reputation is low

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Where do you redraw the chart? Is there an example to test? A jsfiddle?

Comment: i am using jquery 1.9.1.js  if  i put type as column i can see it perfectly fine

Comment: this is the link of snapshot http://httest.in/incentive.png